# blender 3.0 "Snap to" and "propotional editing" icons gone

Tags: interface

[image]

I installed blender3.0 and all items used to be in the top center are gone

Comment: Try reloading factory defaults.

Comment: You seem to be using an addon that messes up with the interface. Try disabling it.